# 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error from anonymous array

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

InquiryOrder Model

```
public class InquiryOrder
{
    [Key]
    public int InquiryOrderId { get; set; }

    public string InquiryOrderName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductType")]
    public int? ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}
```

ProductType Model

```
public class ProductType
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Must be less than 100 charcters", MinimumLength = 1)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string ProductTypeName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<InquiryOrder> inquiryOrders { get; set; }
}
```

InquiryOrder Controller

```
var displayedInquiryOrders = filteredInquiryOrders.Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(iDisplayLength);
        var result = from c in displayedInquiryOrders .AsEnumerable()
                      select new[] { 
                                Convert.ToString(c.InquiryOrderId),
                                c.InquiryOrderName,
                                c.ProductType.ProductTypeName,
                            };
```

Here from `c.ProductType.ProductTypeName`, im getting this error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. Pls help me to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Well, what do you think could be `null` in `c.ProductType`? You are the only one who can run & debug the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here

```
new[] { 
                            Convert.ToString(c.InquiryOrderId),
                            c.InquiryOrderName,
                            c.ProductType.ProductTypeName,
                        };
```

Either:

- `c` is null
- `c.ProductType` is null

Comment: Thanks!. yes i have null values in table and that occurred this error. But how can i adjust this array such that it accepts null values from database?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some NullReference controls. Pls try this:

```
           select new[]{ 
                            Convert.ToString(c?.InquiryOrderId),
                            c?.InquiryOrderName,
                            c?.ProductType?.ProductTypeName,
                        };
```

Comment: Please also note that this works only in C#6 or above.

Comment: You are right. Sorry, i forgot this explanation.